# GRRR VBA Public array variable not working in userform

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, userform

I am creating a macro that counts how many hours I have assigned to a job over a period of a month. I have the code for the list of jobs and time spent on each job working, which saves each job name and the related hours in the array `JobHours(i,j)`. Once I try and access this array in the userform it is not available.

My code in the module

```
Option Explicit
Public JobHours() As Variant

    Sub MonthlyHoursShow()
    Monthly_Hours.Show
End Sub

Sub MonthlyHours(SelMonth As Variant)
'Code which assigns values to JobHours() - 
    ReDim JobHours(1, 0)
    JobHours(0, 0) = "Job Number"
    JobHours(1, 0) = "Hours"
'There are a few loops to determine what values to collect, and they are then
'assigned to JobHours() as follows:
    cValue = UCase(ws.Cells(j, 2).Text)
    ReDim Preserve JobHours(1, JobNum)
        JobHours(0, JobNum) = cValue
        JobHours(1, JobNum) = ws.Cells(j, 27).Value
    Worksheets("25 Mar").Cells(8 + JobNum, 30).Value = JobHours(0, JobNum)
    Worksheets("25 Mar").Cells(8 + JobNum, 31).Value = JobHours(1, JobNum)
'where JobNum is a counter for the number of jobs, and is incremented as part of the loop.

    Debug.Print "Upper Bound of JobHours() = " & UBound(JobHours, 2) - 'Returns as 38
    Debug.Print "Total Number of jobs is " & Application.CountA(JobHours) - 'returns as 78

End Sub
```

and in my userform:

```
Private Sub CalcButton_Click()
SelMonth = MonthBox.Value

Call MonthlyHours(SelMonth)

'Debug.Print "Upper Bound of JobHours() = " & UBound(JobHours, 2) - 'Returns error
Debug.Print "Total Number of jobs is " & Application.CountA(JobHours) - 'Returns as 1

End Sub
```

If I don't comment the `UBound` command in the first `Debug.Print` line the I get the following error:

```
Compile Error: Expected Array
```

My understanding was that if the Array was declared as a public variable it will pass to a userform - In fact I had this working! I then saved the workbook, closed it and reopened and now have the problem??

I have no idea why this isn't working - it is my first real attempt at using an array. If you have any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Dan

Comment: What code assigns the value to `JobHours`? Where is `ubound` being used?

Comment: You must define your "JobHours" array (with at least a `ReDim` statement) before acceding to it (like when you try to get its bounds). Besides when you exit the macro, you lose all variable values, be they `Public` or not. If you want to keep variables values from one macro session to another, you have to store them (maybe in a sheet, or in a txt file) and then retrieve them

Comment: The only way I can see you getting that error is if you have used `JobHours` somewhere else as a routine/module name.

Comment: Thanks @shahkalpesh. I have added some code to show how `JobHours()` is dimensioned and assigned values. I have also added the uBound line to the module code, as well as the form code, to show the different values they return.

Comment: @Rory, I checked all my code and couldn't find anything. It turns out I assigned a text field in the userform the name `JobHours` which was causing the problem. All fields in the userform are now labelled `Job_Hours' and it is all working :) Thanks!

Comment: you must call MonthlyHours before the userform (maybe in userform_activate), or the redim won't be in effect. Also, any interuption of the code (error, debug, designer mode...) will erase the array from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rory I identified that a text field in the userform itself was called `JobHours`, which was causing the errors. It has since been labelled `Job_Hours` and it is all working :)

Thanks everyone for your comments and assistance.

Dan

Comment: you could still keep the same variable name and textbox label ,  if you use it with a reference like this : `UserformName.JobHours`  (or `Me.JobHours` inside the form) , and `ModuleName.JobHours`.      But i wouldn't recommend it (as for the possible confusion)

Answer (score 0):

SInce we don't see all your code and how you populate the array, we can only do guesses.

My guess is that your issue is the `,2` in `UBound(JobHours, 2)`

```
Debug.Print "Upper Bound of JobHours() = " & UBound(JobHours, 2)
```

The second parameter of `Ubound()` is there to optionnaly specify the dimension. This is only usefull if you have a multidimensionnal array. I believe this is not your case and that you tell VBA to access a dimension that does'nt exists.

If I am wrong, edit your question and show us everything.

Comment: Thanks Thomas G, I do have a 2D array, and I have edited my post to show how it is dimensioned and assigned values.